# Alter column datatype in sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to rename the column datatype from text to ntext but getting error

```
Msg 4927, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot alter column 'ColumnName' to be data type ntext.
```

query that i m using is as follows:-

```
alter table tablename alter column columnname ntext null
```

Comment: Have updated re your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion not allowed. Add new column as ntext then copy converted data to new column, then delete old column. Might consume a lot of diskspace if it's a large table!
You should use NVARCHAR(MAX) instead of NTEXT which will not be supported in the future.

[Msg 4927](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/faq/cannot_alter_column_is_p1.aspx)

Comment: Indeed: this works fine ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName nvarchar(max) null

Answer (score 3):

I expect you'll need to copy the data out - i.e. add a scratch column, fill it; drop the old column; add the new column, copy the data back, remove the scratch column:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD tmp text NULL
GO
UPDATE TableName SET tmp = ColumnName
GO
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP COLUMN ColumnName
GO
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD ColumnName ntext NULL
GO
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = tmp
GO
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP COLUMN tmp
```

---

For applying database-wide, you can script it out from info-schema (note you should filter out any system tables etc):

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME+ '] ADD [__tmp] text NULL
GO
UPDATE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME+ '] SET [__tmp] = [' + COLUMN_NAME + ']
GO
ALTER TABLE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME+ '] DROP COLUMN [' + COLUMN_NAME + ']
GO
ALTER TABLE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME+ '] ADD [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] ntext ' +
    CASE IS_NULLABLE WHEN 'YES' THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END + '
GO
UPDATE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME+ '] SET [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = [__tmp]
GO
ALTER TABLE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME+ '] DROP COLUMN [__tmp]'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'text'
```

Comment: Is there any way to use this query for all the table in the database without going through each table individually

Comment: In a word: no. But it would be easy to script the above out using a SELECT from info-schema-tables.

Comment: how can i remove foreign key constraint to alter the table because it is causing error

Comment: You have a foreign key on a text column? Is that even legal? No: I don't have an easy answer to that...

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the query is:

ALTER TABLE [tableName] CHANGE [oldColumnName] [newColumnName] [newColumnType];